# How to render an Entity or a Layer exactly once / in one frame, in QT3D

Tags: qt3d

I am rendering a mesh on screen, and when the user presses a button I am rendering a black square to a texture and then the mesh to the texture. After this I am firing up a compute shader that performs image processing on the "snaphot". My question is: How to do the rendering exactly once?

These are the steps I need to perform:

1. Render black square to texture (to clear texture)
2. Render geometry to texture (to take a snapshot of it so I can process it)
3. Start compute shader with texture as input

I am able to perform the compute shader exactly one time using the trigger(1) command (technically this was not straightforward though : https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-86493).

However, how do I render the black square and then the mesh (step 1&2) to a texture exactly one time?
Ideally I would like to start the compute shader just after step 1&2 are finished, and it is important that step 1&2 stop being executed after step 3 is executed, or else the result from 3 will be overwritten, and this is the problem I am facing now in my qt3d application.

I guess I could just set the  property on the qt3d entities to true, and then to false, and then start the compute shader. But how do I know when to set enabled back to false? If I do it too early, they might get turned on and off before they have had time to get rendered.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand completely what you want. Do I understand correctly that you have a mesh that the user can view and when they like they can take a "screenshot" of the mesh which you want to apply post-processing to? For rendering to a texture I'd recommend my [offscreen renderer](https://github.com/florianblume/Qt3D-OffscreenRenderer). For the controlling the rendering I have multiple suggestions but don't know which will fit you best: You could set the rendering mode on you `QRenderSettings` to `onDemand`. This only renders something when something in the scene changes.

Comment: For example, when you set an entity to enabled, this will cause the renderer to render due to the property notification system of Qt3D. I'm not sure I fully understand fences in OpenGL but there are also `QSetFence` and `QWaitFence` which you could use to ensure that the shader computation has finished.

Comment: Then you could also set the drive mode of the `QAspectEngine` to `manual` (only from Qt >= 5.14). Then you can manually call `processFrame` which processes a single frame. Other than that I think you can have a `QClearBuffers` in the offscreen texture rendering framegraph branch which clears the texture (no need to render a black triangle, that's a lot quicker). So, and you then have a render capture in the framegraph branch of the post-processing shader? Did I get that right? And that's too slow?

Comment: The last thing I can think of is to maybe implement your own aspect which disables the branch that renders the mesh to the texture. You can read [here](https://www.kdab.com/writing-custom-qt-3d-aspect/) on how to implement your own aspect.

Comment: Thanks for your answers Florian, I have seen many of your other qt3d answers elsewhere and they have been very helpful!   Yes you understood the problem correctly, and I will try out your QSetFence suggestion first. I thought it would work with the solution I had because I have step 1,2 and 3 after each other in the framegraph and they all have MemoryBarrier.ShaderImageAccess. But it seems like the compute shader (step 3) is not quite in sync with step 1 and 2